# com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.SqlException: Invalid argument: unknown column name COL1

Tags: exception, db2, invalid-argument

i was getting this error **com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.SqlException: Invalid argument: unknown column** **name COL1** when trying to access my resultSet with rs.getString("COL1").
My SQL Query is: **Select UPPER(COL1) from table1.**
the same query and Java code is working fine with **DB2 v8(Type 2 driver)** but it is throwing the above exception when using with **DB2 v9(Type 4 driver).**

However i am able to resolve this error by adding an alias,
modified query: **Select UPPER(COL1) COL1 from table1.**

the above query is working with both DB2 v8 and v9.
does this mean, in DB2 9 we must provide an alias when using with functions like (upper,trim,..)???

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in DB2 or SQL requires the column names of functions to be specific values.

It may be that the earlier drivers (or even the t2 drivers, which I would generally never use anymore, preferring t4 myself) gave you a column name you expected but I wonder what it would have given you for `col1 | '.' | col2`.

Your query really *should* be what you have to get it working:

```
select upper(col1) as col1 from table1
```

This guarantees the column name is `col1`.

If you really want to know what the column names are for your query, you can retrieve the meta data for the result set with the following calls (examples only):

```
ResultSet rs = <get your result set here>;
ResultSetMeatData meta = rs.getMetaData();
for (int i = 1; i < meta.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    System.out.println (getColumnName (i));
}
```

But you should be using the `as` clause to ensure the names are as expected.